# Why would Internet explorer not allow changing the type of an input?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, passwords

I have written a modern login form where 'Username' is written in one field, but is grey, when you click it, it vanishes and also turns the text black, I also have a 'Password' on that starts as a text input, but when you click on it, it is supposed to change to a password type, but it remains text. This seams to only appear on IE8? why and is there a work around?

```
onFocus='if (this.value == "Password"){ this.value = ""; this.type = "password";}'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Input type swapping broken in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435682/html-input-type-swapping-broken-in-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer's DOM implementation wasn't designed to handle dynamically changing INPUT types. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534700.aspx.

As a workaround, you can have a hidden password field and then switch visibility between the text box and the password field.